# How to delete file from directory using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a asp.net website folder namely `Website3` inside `website3` folder there is a upload folder. I want to delete files inside upload folder on button click event.

MY directory status :

```
Website3 > upload
```

I'm using the following command but it doesn't delete the file from upload directory

```
Protected Sub ListView1_ItemDeleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDeletedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemDeleted
        Dim lab As Label = CType(ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedValue).FindControl("photoLabel"), Label)
        System.IO.File.Delete(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName("/upload/") & lab.Text)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx)

```
File.Delete((MapPath(".") + ("\\" + lab.Text)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
Public Function DelAllUploadedFiles()    
For Each Uploadedfiles As var In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/upload/"))        
System.IO.File.Delete(Uploadedfiles )   
Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put try and catch and see if you have
Exception . In general in order to delete in IIS process pool ,should be defined under strong user .

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set the folder settings on the server
who can enter this folder and has delete authority
Login to your server account and give delete permission to the folder to everyone